# Exporting time series response data for VS2013 load tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am trying to figure out how to export and then analyze the results of a load test, but after the test is over it seems I cannot find the data for each individual request by url. This data shows during the load test itself, but after it is over it seems as if that data is no longer accessible and all I can find are totals. The data that I want is under the "Page response time" graph on the graphs window during the test. I know this is not the response time for every single request and is probably averaged, but that would suffice for the calculations I want to make.

I have looked in the database on my local machine (LoadTest2010, where all of the summary data is stored) and I cannot find the data I'm looking for. I am load testing a single page application, fyi.

My goal is to plot (probably in excel) each request url against the user load and analyze the slope of the response time averages to determine which requests scale the worst (and best). During the load test I can see this data and get a visual idea but when it ends I cannot seem to find it to export.

A) Can this data be exported from within visual studio? Is there a setting required to make VS persist this data to the database? I have, from under Run Settings, the "Results" section "Timing Details Storage" set to "All individual details" and the Storage Type set to "Database".

B) Is this data in any of the tables in the LoadTest2010 database where all of the summary data is stored? It might be easier to query manually if its not spread out overly, but all I was able to find was summary data.

Comment: If the "update with answer" is an answer then it would be better to post it as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: Good call, I wasnt sure I could answer myself and I was in a hurry, fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the data in the database that I wanted. The tables I needed were the WebLoadTestRequestMap (which has the request URI's in it) and the LoadTestPageDetail (which has the individual response times themselves). They can be joined on webloadtestrequestmap.requestId and loadtestpagedetail.pageId (unintuitively).

I do have the "Results" section "Timing Details Storage" set to "All individual details" and the Storage Type set to "Database", it did not seem like every load tests results were available, maybe because of this setting.

More data on the layout of the load test database here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database.aspx